# Are events guaranteed to go off?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Let's say I have a form SomeForm that inherits from Form.

```
public class SomeForm : Form
{
    private void SomeForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("FormClosed event in SomeForm class");
    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    SomeForm someForm = new SomeForm();
    someForm = null; //Ideally the messagebox would display here
    SomeForm someForm = new SomeForm();
    someForm.Close();  //Messagebox would display in this case as well
}
```

I want to show that MessageBox whenever the form is closed.  Should I stick that in the FormClosed event?  Is it safe to assume that the FormClosed event will fire every time something like the destructor is run?  Is there a better place to put this code that must occur when the form is closed?

**EDIT**

Someone made a good point in the comments below.  It seems the event does not fire when the instance of the class is set to null.  However, will the destructor or some other method still be called when the instance is set to null.  I want to guarantee that my code runs when the user is finished with the class.

I'm also aware that forcibly shutting down the system, ending the process, acts of God, etc will not cause my code to run no matter what.  =)

Comment: There are certainly answers to your question, as posed. But wouldn't time be better spent on solving whichever problem you thought could be solved by relying on these events firing?

Comment: define "finished with the class" - you're still leaving too much open. As a first step, describe *one* concrete scenario that you're dealing with/thinking of, and any additional scenarios you've identified.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My question came about from a theoretical discussion.  It just led me to question the reliability of events.

Comment: if you're relying on events for a *security* reason, or an *integrity* reason, then you need to revisit those decisions. For anything else, I can't think of why you'd *require* an event to occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will be called unless something exceptionably happens, like killing it via system commands or pulling the plug. Other cases include

1. setting the variable to `null` (not calling the `Close` method)
2. Exception in another delegate: All events are `MulticastDelegate`s, and the delegates are executed in order of appearence in that `MulticastDelegate`, if one of the previous delegates before yours causes an exception, your delegate will not be called.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It will get called unless your executable is forcibly closed (via task manager or `taskkill` from the command line) or the program crashes.</strike>

EDIT: I did some experimentation and found the following:

- If you set your reference to the form to null, the form remains visible, and when the form is closed, the event gets raised.
- If your form is a child form and the main form gets closed, the child form closes WITHOUT the event being raised.
- If you call the form's `Hide()` method, the event does NOT get raised.  Subsequently closing the main form, as mentioned above, will not cause the event to get raised.
- Overriding `OnClosed()` will not help because it's still not called if the main form is closed.
- Calling the form's `Dispose()` method (which is what the GC would eventually do if nothings pointing at it) will also not cause the event to get raised.

It looks like there really isn't a way to GUARANTEE the code will get called from within the form.  You can put the code after the `Application.Run();` in your `Main()` and it will get called there.  There's also an event for `Application.ApplicationExit` that would get called unless you have exceptional circumstances (forcibly closed or crash).

You can register a handler for the `Application.ApplicationExit` event in your form, but be aware that by this time, your object has already been disposed, so you can't do anything with it.

Comment: What if a `SomeForm` instance is set to `null`, or reinstantiated?

Comment: it isn't closed and thus the event isn't called.

Comment: I'll admit that's a somewhat contrived case, but the OP did ask "Is it safe to assume that the FormClosed event will fire every time something like the destructor is run?"

Answer (score 0):

FormClosed event is raised by OnClosed method. So if you want certain level of guarantee, you can override OnClosed method.